# How to format query results into my extended dictionary object?

Tags: python, sql

I have SQL tables:

Question

| q_id (PK) | userID(FK User(userID)) | question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | "What is between 1 and 4?" |
| 2 | 222 | "What is between 5 and 7?" |

Answer

| a_id (PK) | q_id(FK Question(q_id)) | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | '2' |
| 2 | 1 | '3' |
| 3 | 2 | '6' |

In Python, I extend dict so that it has predefined keys for questions and answers:

```
class MyQuestion(dict):
    def __init__(self, question, answers):
        self['question'] = question
        self['answers'] = answers
```

My goal is to end up with a list of MyQuestion objects(question_list). Currently I am doing something like this and it works:

```
question_list = []
cursor.execute("SELECT q_id, question FROM question WHERE user_id =(%s)", userID)
result = cursor.fetchall()
   for question in result:
     cursor.execute("SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE q_id = (%s)", question[0])
     answers = cursor.fetchall()
     question_list.append(MyQuestion( question[1], answers ) )
```

I want to modify this so that only one query needs to be made. So I created a query that gets all answers for every question that a user has asked and I want the same results as above.

```
SELECT answer.answer, question.question
FROM answer 
Left JOIN question on answer.q_id=question.q_id 
WHERE question.user_id = (%s), userID)
```

How do I format my results my list of MyQuestions objects?

Comment: Can you clarify second to last question? Why not fetch from that joined query to your list? Also, *better* heads us toward opinionated answers which is off-topic on StackOverflow. We answer attempted code that has issues: errors or undesired results.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my question, I'll re-edit it. I was struggling  to wrap my head around how I could format my results from the query into my class, but figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT answer.answer, question.question FROM answer Left JOIN question on answer.q_id=question.q_id WHERE question.user_id = (%s)", userID)
result = cursor.fetchall()
question_list = []
my_questions = {}
    for answer in result:
        if answer[1] in my_questions.keys():
            my_questions[answer[1]]['answers'].append(answer[0])
        else:
            my_questions[answer[1]] = MyQuestion(answer[1], [answer[0]])
            
    question_list =  my_questions.value()
```

After querying using the joined query, organize results into a dictionary using the question string as a key. The key can also be the q_id.

For every row in the query if the question already exists as a key, go to value MyQuestion object and append the answer to MyQuestion['answer']. Otherwise add the question as a key with a new MyQuestion object.

Return the values of the my_questions dictionary for the list of MyQuestions.